# Remap already bound keys with xmodmap

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I recently bought a 17" LG Gram and I want to remap some of the keys to be more like my 80% keyboard. Using a tiling window manager (qtile), it's nice to have a Super key on both the left and right sides of the keyboard, but currently there is only a Super on the left.

So what I'm trying to do is remap Control_R to be Super_R and remap keypad 0 (also the "Insert" key) to be Control_R. (I still have access to 0 at the top row).

I've tried a few different things follwing examples [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1296401/xmodmap-how-to-remap-keys-and-disable-the-original-ones) with no luck. Using `xev` I find that the right control key is `keycode 105` and the keypad 0 (insert) key is `keycode 90`. Note that the keypad 0 (insert) key is `keycode 90` regardless of whether the NumLk key is pressed.

So I've tried

```
keycode 90 = Control_R
keycode 105 = Super_R
```

which doesn't work since some keys need to be unmapped. So I've tried

```
clear Control
keycode 37 = Control_L
keycode 90 = Control_R
keycode 105 = Super_R
```

and then this new Super_R works as intended, but neither control works. Now I wouldn't necessary expect this new Control_R to work on the newly mapped key since keypad 0 (insert key) hasn't been unmapped yet, but why isn't `Control_L` working?

I've also tried

```
clear Control
keycode 37 =
keycode 37 = Control_L
keycode 90 = Control_R
keycode 105 = Super_R
```

but no luck.

So, after unmapping Control, I want to (a) map Control_L back to what it was originally and (b) unmap keypad 0 (insert) key and map that one to Control_R.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
clear Control
keycode 37 = Control_L
keycode 90 = Control_R
keycode 105 = Super_R
add Control = Control_L Control_R
```

Order matters too. I originally had `keycode 105 = Super_R` at the end but I had to move that in front of the final line.

The [Arch wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) was helpful.